# R plotly - sankey chart not returned

Tags: r, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am running below code in RStudio, and want to create sankey chart with plotly. code runs without error. but the sankey chart is not displayed.  what's wrong here?

```py
library("plotly")
a = read.csv('cleanSankey.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = a$value)

nodes_with_position <- data.frame(
  "id" = names,
  "label" = node_names,
  "x" = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7),
  "y" = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
)

#Plot
plot_ly(type='sankey',
        orientation = "h",
        
        node = list(
          label = node_names,
          x = nodes_with_position$x,
          y = nodes_with_position$y,
          color = "grey",
          pad = 15,
          thinkness = 20,
          line = list(color = "grey", width = 0.5)),
 
         link = list(
           source = links$source,
           target = links$target,
           value = links$value))
```

sankey is plotted , but and nodes for second layer goes to last layer. How to fix the node position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define the node position by setting the `arrangement` argument to stop plotly from automatically justifying the position.

This requires some finessing as you need to specify the coordinates of the nodes. You can find more details here: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position

### Code

```
library(plotly)

a <- read.csv("~/cleanSankey.csv")

node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))

# added id column for clarity, but it's likely not needed
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = 0:(length(node_names)-1),
  name = node_names
)

links <- data.frame(
  source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
  target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
  value = a$value
)

# set the coordinates of the nodes
nodes$x <- c(0, 1, 0.5)
nodes$y <- c(0, 0.5, 1)

# plot - note the `arrangement="snap"` argument
plot_ly(
  type='sankey',
  orientation = "h",
  arrangement="snap", # can also change this to 'fixed'
  node = list(
    label = nodes$name,
    x = nodes$x,
    y = nodes$y,
    color = "grey",
    pad = 15,
    thinkness = 20,
    line = list(color = "grey", width = 0.5)
  ),
  link = list(
    source = links$source,
    target = links$target,
    value = links$value
  )
)
```

Plot output with arrangement="snap":

[image: Sankey plot with arrangement set to "snap"]

Comment: I think you just need to add `arrangement="snap"` to your `plot_ly` function. If that doesn't work, try `arrangement="fixed"`

Comment: I have 8 layers/columns in sankey chart. I got error "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame" based on your suggestion. code is update in post.

Comment: tried add arrangement parameter, still failed. the error still is Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Comment: Do you get the error with the example data I provided or a different data set?

Comment: i am using my own dataset. I post some sample csv data in the post.

Comment: got it, I'll see if I can reproduce with the csv sample

Comment: The error is because `"id" = names,` is trying to assign the `names()` function as a column of the data.frame. It seems there are only three nodes but there are 8 coordinates. How many nodes are you expecting there to be?

Comment: totally there're 28 nodes in my csv file, the max number of nodes in a layer/column is 18.

Comment: I'll update my answer with new code

Comment: I've updated my answer using the sample csv data